# Limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{\sin x}\sin \frac{1}{t} \cos t^{2}\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits

Determine whether or not the limit below exists.
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{\sin x}\sin \frac{1}{t} \cos t^{2}\mathrm{d}t$$
I tried to use the Mean value theorem integrals to prove the limit exists, but it does not exist for $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\sin \frac{1}{x}$. So I guessed the limit does not exist and used the Cauchy principle to prove it, but I failed.

Any idea will be helpful.

Comment: Use L'Hospital's rule followed by Leibnitz's rule for differentiation under integration sign . You'll see that the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: @PNDas : But L'Hopital's Rule can't be used to show that a limit doesn't exist (except in the sense of being infinite, which is not what we have here). We only have that the liminf and limsup of the original quotient lie between the liminf and limsup of the quotient of the derivatives.

Comment: @TobyBartels: Indeed you are correct -- non-existence of $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ does not mean that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ cannot exist.

Comment: Nice question +1 The key is to note that the factor $\cos t^2$ in integrand can be effectively replaced by $1$. See details in my answer.

Comment: @PNDas: The fundamental problem with LHospital Rule is that usually people forget the exact conditions under which it works.  Here the ratio of derivatives does not tend to a finite or infinite limit and hence the rule is not guaranteed to work. Use this rule only as a last resort. Usually other techniques are simpler and more powerful (remember your friend Taylor if needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here is a slightly different approach.

Note that $(\sin x) /x\to 1$ as $x\to 0$ and hence (add missing steps here if you need) the desired limit equals the limit of $$\frac {1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\sin(1/t)\cos t^2\,dt$$ and we can write the above expression as $$\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\sin(1/t)(\cos t^2-1)\,dt+\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x\sin(1/t)\,dt$$ The integrand in first integral tends to $0$ as $t\to 0$. Therefore by the fundamental theorem of calculus (part 1) the first term above tends to $0$.

The desired limit thus equals $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {1}{x}\int_0^x\sin(1/t)\,dt$$ This is a famous question on this website and the desired limit is $0$. You can prove this by using the auxiliary function $$g(x) =x^2\cos(1/x),x\neq 0,g(0)=0$$ We have $$g'(x) =2x\cos(1/x)+\sin(1/x),x\neq 0,g'(0)=0$$ By fundamental theorem of calculus (part 2) we have $$g(x) =g(x) - g(0)=\int_0^x g'(t) \, dt$$ which means that $$\frac {1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}\sin(1/t)\,dt=\frac{g(x)}{x}-2\cdot\frac{1}{x}\int_0^x t\cos(1/t)\,dt$$ Now the first term on right tends to $g'(0)=0$ and second term on right also tends to $0$ (via fundamental theorem of calculus (part 1) as the integrand tends to $0$ as $t\to 0$).

You should also observe that the above derivation works in case $\cos t^2$ is replaced by any Riemann integrable function $\phi(t)$ which tends to $1$ as $t\to 0$.

---

For those wondering about the version of FTC used in above I state them explicitly.

**FTC Part 1**: Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be a function which is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$. Then the function $F:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ defined by $$F(x) =\int_a^x f(t) \, dt$$ is continuous on $[a, b] $. Further if $c\in[a, b] $ is a point such that right hand limit of $f$ at $c$ is $L$ then the right hand derivative of $F$ at $c$ exists and equals $L$ (the statement holds if *right* is replaced by *left*).

**FTC Part 2**: Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb {R} $ be Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $ and let $F:[a, b] \to \mathbb {R} $ be continuous on $[a, b] $ and differentiable on $(a, b) $ with $F'(x) =f(x)\, \forall x\in(a, b) $ then $$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx=F(b) - F(a) $$

Answer (score 6):

Since $\cos t^2$ is monotone decreasing for $t$ sufficiently close to $0$, by the second mean value theorem for integrals there exists $\xi_x \in (0, \sin x)$ such that

$$\int_0^{\sin x} \sin \frac{1}{t} \cos t^2 \, dt = \cos(0) \int_0^{\xi_x}\sin \frac{1}{t}  \, dt = \int_0^{\xi_x}\sin \frac{1}{t}  \, dt$$

Taking $g(t) = t^2 \cos \frac{1}{t}$ for $t > 0$ and $g(0) = 0$,  we have $g’(0) =0$ and for $t>0$,

$$g'(t) = 2t \cos \frac{1}{t} + \sin \frac{1}{t},$$ and, using the FTC,

$$\int_0^{\xi_x}\sin \frac{1}{t}  \, dt = \int_0^{\xi_x} g'(t) \, dt-\int_0^{\xi_x}2t \cos \frac{1}{t} \, dt=\xi_x^2\cos \frac{1}{\xi_x} -  \int_0^{\xi_x}2t \cos \frac{1}{t} \, dt$$

Thus,

$$\frac{1}{x} \int_0^{\sin x} \sin \frac{1}{t} \cos t^2 \, dt = \xi_x \frac{\xi_x}{x}\cos \frac{1}{\xi_x} - \frac{1}{x} \int_0^{\xi_x}2t \cos \frac{1}{t} \, dt$$

We can apply the mean value theorem to the integral on the RHS (since the integrand is continuous) to find $\theta_x \in (0,\xi_x)$ such that

$$\frac{1}{x} \int_0^{\sin x} \sin \frac{1}{t} \cos t^2 \, dt = \xi_x \frac{\xi_x}{x}\cos \frac{1}{\xi_x} - \frac{\xi_x}{x} 2\theta_x \cos \frac{1}{\theta_x} $$

Since $\xi_x/x < 1$, we have

$$\left|\frac{1}{x} \int_0^{\sin x} \sin \frac{1}{t} \cos t^2 \, dt\right| \leqslant \xi_x +2 \theta_x$$

Since $\xi_x , \theta_x \to 0$ as $x  \to 0+$, we get

$$\lim_{x \to 0+}\frac{1}{x} \int_0^{\sin x} \sin \frac{1}{t} \cos t^2 \, dt = 0$$

Similarly we can show that the limit as $x \to 0-$ is $0$ as well.

Comment: +1 there. I avoided mean value theorem for integrals in my answer.